# Remove hexadecimal characters from URL

Tags: java, url, url-encoding

Please deal with this trivial question.

I am getting some URLs like `"SOME_DOMAIN?q\x3dnintendo+mathe\x26um\x3d1\x26ie\x3dUTF-8\x26tbm\x3dshop\x26cid\x3d8123694338777545283\x26sa\x3dX\x26ei\x3dL8cjUJmHO8L30gGa1ICgCw\x26ved\x3d0CI4BEIIIMAk"` which contains some escape characters.

What is the best way to remove these hexadecimal characters? I have this below snippet which solves my problem as of now but doesn't look like a reliable solution.

```
    url = url.replace("\\x2F","/");
    url = url.replace("\\x26","&");
    url = url.replace("\\x3d","=");
    url = url.replace("\\x2F","/");
    url = url.replace("\\x2F","/");
```

I haven't faced this issue but spaces might appear between the URL. Should `URLDecoder.decode` solve my problem?

Kindly advice.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any control over where you're getting them from? If I was doing this I'd be looking to fix it there rather than at this point? If not, you can URLDecode it

Comment: donald.. I am getting it from any random website which I don't have any control over.
@Nishant Yeah, Thanks, I was missing the part where we should replace the '\x' with '%'!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works

```
   URLDecoder.decode(yourURLString.replace("\\x", "%"), "UTF-8")
```

see this in action :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String s = "SOME_DOMAIN?q\\x3dnintendo+mathe\\x26um\\x3d1\\x26ie\\x3dUTF-8\\x26tbm\\x3dshop\\x26cid\\x3d8123694338777545283\\x26sa\\x3dX\\x26ei\\x3dL8cjUJmHO8L30gGa1ICgCw\\x26ved\\x3d0CI4BEIIIMAk";
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(s.replace("\\x", "%"), "UTF-8"));

}
```

returns

```
SOME_DOMAIN?q=nintendo mathe&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=8123694338777545283&sa=X&ei=L8cjUJmHO8L30gGa1ICgCw&ved=0CI4BEIIIMAk
```

---

Basically, you need to replace `\x` with `%` and decode it using:

```
 URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

see here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: What if URL contains '+' in between? Won't is put a space and cause issues? Should we explicitly fix that issue?

Comment: @instanceOfObject dude, did you really test this code? It will take barely 6 seconds to place a `+` in between and test.

Comment: Yes, I did and and anyways decoder replaces '+' with ' '. That's why I asked this question. Because in this scenario, new URL which will be created will have spaces in between. We should encode this URL before using it to handle this case.

Comment: the standard encoding replaces `SPACE` with `+`; so decoding will always change plus to space. You may want to `decodedString.replace(" ", "+")` -- hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, That's what I said! Thanks btw!